# Desired State Configuration - Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, dsc

I am looking to create an extra user in our VM by using ARM and DSC.
This looks pretty easy, however, I can't find how to set the type of user account.

What kind of account is made of when this feature is executed? Will the user have administrator rights by default? I prefer the user to not have admin rights on the machine when it's created. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As a regular local user. You can then add it to different groups using group management.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/userresource
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/groupresource